# Why doesn't the zoom ring on my Vivitar 75-205mm lens turn?

Tags: lens, zoom, minolta

I bought a Vivitar 75-205mm zoom macro lens for Minolta MD yesterday without paying much attention to the seller's details:

[image: the lens, side] [image: the lens, front]

I bought it as a gift to someone important for me. She only has a 35mm lens, and once told me she would like to have the ability to have some flexibility in terms of distances, so what I was looking for was a lens with variable focal length like the Nikon 55-200mm I have for my D3200 DSLR.

The thing is that when I tried it at home, once mounted in the camera, I couldn't change the zoom. I got very angry with myself on realizing how little I know about the world of lenses.

My question is, why does this lens have 75-205mm printed on it if it doesn't zoom? Also, why does it 3.8-4.8 if you can't 'swipe' through it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reminds me of one of my FD mount lenses where you pull\push to adjust focal length, rotate to adjust focus, and then there is the aperture ring for...well adjusting the aperture.

I don't quite understand what you mean when you say 'swipe' through the aperture settings. It is a variable aperture so, when it is at 205mm it has an aperture of 4.8 as opposed 75mm having 3.8

Comment: Oh crap... I never tryied to pull push, that worked ! I feel like an A**hole ,sorry and thank you !!

Comment: Anyways , the feeling you get using these lenses are much much better than the one i have for my dlsr (i mean when you focus and  zoom in and out, etc)